# Change size of /root patition in ubuntu 16.04 LVM

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, lvm, 16.04

I installed ubuntu 16.04 with these settings 
"Erase Disk and install Ubuntu" with "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation" checked
I have a 1tb hard drive and all that 1tb is now in the root partition excluding 4gb swap. How do I decrease the partition of root and make a new partition.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is backup your most important data in case of a mistake.  Then use the LVM resize commands.

You can find images of procedures on this link:

[How to Extend/REduce LVM's in Linux - Part II](http://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/)

The actuall commands to reduce the size are:

```
resize2fs - Reduce a file-system
lvreduce  - Reduce a Logical volume
```

For GUI you can try [system-config-lvm](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/system-config-lvm/) from the Ubuntu repository.

You might consider installing Ubuntu on a Pen-drive.  Boot to the pen-drive then install the LVM gui on that drive and manage your hard drive from that session.

Comment: I've read somewhere that gparted doesn't support LVM. Thanks anyways

Comment: Sorry.  I updated my answer for LVMs.

Comment: Any GUI method for this?

Comment: @DJ18 Yes.  Try `system-config.lvm` from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me all days:

**Check disk**

```
e2fsck -ff /dev/vg0/test-disk
```

**Resize filesystem to 4G:**

```
resize2fs /dev/vg0/test-disk 4G
```

Check disk again just for the sake of it (first command).

***Remember to backup important files.***